# Request [503] in requests and User Agent isn't working

Tags: html, http, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to access this website via Python, which first requires a log-in:
https://nitrogensports.eu/

This is my script so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, urllib, html5lib

url = 'https://nitrogensports.eu/'
user_agent = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers = user_agent)
```

This gives me:

```
<Response [503]>
```

I've logged into websites before by inspecting elements for the username and password box and what not, but I am not even able to get the first HTML tree with this website. I've tried some other things such as changeing my user_agent to:

```
user_agent = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64;en; rv:5.0) Gecko/20110619 Firefox/5.0'
```

but I keep getting 503

Could someone help me retrieve even the HTML structure of the webpage without anything to do with username of password? Thanks

Comment: Also I don't think this a server issue as I can open the website via Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work but must just be the login page

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

url = 'https://nitrogensports.eu/'

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

response = http.request('GET', url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, 'lxml')
```

You will still need to log on I'm sure I've logged in before with out needing to go through all of this I'll some of my old work and see if i can find it. Inspect the elements but yeah done that before too.

This [website](https://linode.com/docs/applications/big-data/how-to-scrape-a-website-with-beautiful-soup/) may help with this method for the rest of your code.